# my html is not linking with my css on chrome os

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-os

my code is not linking with my css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="slylesheet" text="text/css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="beens.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">games</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

it worked on my flash drive but not localy

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    background: rgb(51, 146, 153);
}
li {
  color: rgb(142, 15, 15);
}
```

my background is still white plz help

i tryed rewriting my link code and checking here

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your dir structure for this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo here: `<link href="main.css" rel="slylesheet" text="text/css">`

It is supposed to be `stylesheet`

Also you are calling your header as a class `.header`
But since you didnt give it a class and want to call the tag you need to set it to

```
header {
    background: rgb(51, 146, 153);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```css
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    background: rgb(51, 146, 153);
}
li {
  color: rgb(142, 15, 15);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="slylesheet" text="text/css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="beens.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">games</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this c

If it doesnt work then the problem is the code below the

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

**That's standard code:**

```
li a {
  color: RGB(142, 15, 15);}
```